# Gulp minify, some tasks unfinished

Tags: gulp

I am using gulp to copy my javascript/css files to my dist folder. Sometimes it works, but sometimes 2 tasks remain unfinished. I thought this was a timing problem so I already installed run-sequence, but even with that and .on('end') callbacks my code just doesn't seem to work. So I might have been missing soemthing else.

/// 
/*
This file in the main entry point for defining Gulp tasks and using Gulp plugins.
Click here to learn more. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=518007
*/

```
'use strict';

// include plug-ins
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var clean = require('gulp-clean')
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css');
var angularFilesort = require('gulp-angular-filesort');
var minify = require('gulp-minify');
var rev = require('gulp-rev');
var revFormat = require('gulp-rev-format');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

var config =
{
    //Include all js files but exclude any min.js files
    jsSrc: ['./client/app/**/*.module.js', './client/app/**/*.js'],
    cssSrc: ['./client/css/errorPage.css', './client/css/fonts.css', './client/css/loginPage.css'],

    minimalJsSrc: [
        'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'
    ],
    minimalCss: [
        'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    ],
    vendorjs: [
       'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
       'node_modules/angular/angular.min.js',
       'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
       'node_modules/angular-filter/dist/angular-filter.min.js',
       'node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js',
       'node_modules/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js',
       'node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js',
       'node_modules/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.min.js',
       'node_modules/ui-select/dist/select.min.js',
       'node_modules/angular-ui-sortable/sortable.min.js',
       'node_modules/restangular/dist/restangular-min.js',
       'node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.js',
       'node_modules/sortablejs/Sortable.min.js',
       'node_modules/adal-angular/dist/adal.min.js',
       'node_modules/adal-angular/lib/adal-angular.js',
       'node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.min.js',
       'node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js',
       'node_modules/moment/min/moment-with-locales.min.js',
       'node_modules/moment-timezone/builds/moment-timezone-with-data.js',
       'node_modules/underscore/underscore-min.js',
       'node_modules/sortablejs/Sortable.min.js',
       'node_modules/restangular/dist/restangular.min.js',
       'node_modules/ngstorage/ngStorage.min.js',
       'Client/app/layout/bootstrap.file-input.js',
       'node_modules/ui-router-extras/release/ct-ui-router-extras.min.js',
       'node_modules/ui-router-extras/release/modular/ct-ui-router-extras.core.min.js',
       'node_modules/ui-router-extras/release/modular/ct-ui-router-extras.future.min.js',
       'node_modules/angular-wizard/dist/angular-wizard.min.js',
       'node_modules/api-check/dist/api-check.min.js',
       'node_modules/angular-formly/dist/formly.min.js',
       'node_modules/angular-formly-templates-bootstrap/dist/angular-formly-templates-bootstrap.min.js',
       'node_modules/ng-office-ui-fabric/ngOfficeUiFabric.min.js',
       'node_modules/bootbox/bootbox.min.js',
       'scripts/ui-bootstrap-1.1.2.min.js',
       'scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.1.2.js',
       'node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js',
       'node_modules/datatables.net-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.js',
       'node_modules/angular-datatables/dist/angular-datatables.min.js',
       'node_modules/angular-translate/dist/angular-translate.min.js',
       'node_modules/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.js',
       'node_modules/applicationinsights-js/dist/ai.0.js',
        'node_modules/powerbi-client/dist/powerbi.min.js',

        'node_modules/angular-ui-tinymce/dist/tinymce.min.js',
        'node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.min.js',
        'node_modules/tinymce/themes/modern/theme.min.js',
        'node_modules/tinymce/themes/modern/theme.js',
        'node_modules/tinymce/themes/inlite/theme.js',
        'node_modules/tinymce/themes/mobile/theme.js',
        'node_modules/tinymce/plugins/insertdatetime/plugin.min.js',
        'node_modules/tinymce/plugins/table/plugin.min.js',
        'node_modules/tinymce/plugins/wordcount/plugin.min.js',
        'node_modules/tinymce/plugins/link/plugin.min.js',
        'node_modules/tinymce/plugins/paste/plugin.min.js',
        'node_modules/tinymce/plugins/code/plugin.min.js'
    ],
    vendorCss: [
        'node_modules/toastr/toastr.min.css',
        'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        'node_modules/ui-select/dist/select.min.css',
        'node_modules/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.min.css',
        'node_modules/angular-wizard/dist/angular-wizard.min.css',
        'node_modules/office-ui-fabric/dist/css/fabric.min.css',
        'node_modules/office-ui-fabric/dist/css/fabric.components.min.css',
        'node_modules/office-ui-fabric-core/dist/css/fabric.min.css',
        'node_modules/datatables.net-responsive-dt/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css',
        'node_modules/angular-datatables/dist/css/angular-datatables.min.css',
        'node_modules/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.css',
        'node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css',
        'node_modules/open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css',
    ]
}

gulp.task('clean', function () {
    gulp.src('./client/dist/*')
    .pipe(clean({ force: true }));

    return;
});


gulp.task('minify-js', function(done) {
    gulp.src(config.jsSrc)
    .pipe(concat('all.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify({ mangle: false }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./client/dist'))
    .on('end', function() {
        done();
    });

});

//used for the login and error page

gulp.task('minimal-package-js', function (done) {
    gulp.src(config.minimalJsSrc)
        .pipe(concat('minimal-package.js'))
        .pipe(uglify({ mangle: false }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./client/dist'))
        .on('end', function () {
            done();
        });
});

gulp.task('minify-js-vendor', function () {
    gulp.src(config.vendorjs)
    .pipe(concat('vendor.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./client/dist'))
    return;
});

gulp.task('copy-bootstrap', function(done) {
    gulp.src('node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./client/dist'))
    .on('end', function () {
        done();
    });
});

gulp.task('copy-fonts', function () {
    gulp.src(['node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/*', 'node_modules/open-iconic/font/fonts/*', 'node_modules/bootstrap/fonts/*'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./client/fonts'));
    return;
});

gulp.task('minify-css', function () {
    gulp.src(config.cssSrc)
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(concat('all.min.css'))

    .pipe(gulp.dest('./client/dist'))
    return;
});

gulp.task('minify-css-vendor', function () {

    gulp.src(config.vendorCss)
    .pipe(concat('vendor.min.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./client/dist'))
    return;

});


//Set a default tasks

gulp.task('default', function() {
    return runSequence('clean', [
        'copy-fonts',
        'minimal-package-js',
        'minify-js',
        'minify-js-vendor',
        'minify-css',
        'minify-css-vendor',
        'copy-bootstrap',
        ])
});


function errorHandler(error) {
    console.log(error.toString());
    this.emit('end');
}
```

The error log stays empty, hence I do not know where to look anymore.

[image]

[image]

Any ideas would be appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You have to return **the stream** in your tasks, not just return from the end of the task. See [signal task completion](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/async-completion#signal-task-completion) and examples therein.

> When a stream, promise, event emitter, child process, or observable is
>   returned from a task, the success or error informs gulp whether to
>   continue or end.

So

```
gulp.task('clean', function () {
  return gulp.src('./client/dist/*')
    .pipe(clean({ force: true }));

  // return;
});
```

Make that change for all your tasks.